# How to arrange text into single line and center (align) it horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Could somebody give advice, how to arrange text into single line and center (align) it horizontally?

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;

words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 6000);
```

```css
.text2 {
  font-family: Quicksand-Medium;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;

  height: 40px;
  top: 30%;
  margin-top: -20px;


  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

.word {
  font-family: Quicksand-Medium;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: pre;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<div class="text2" style="z-index:100; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-size: 25px" ><center>
  <p2>Mes siūlome
    <span class="word wisteria">pastovų darbą.</span>
    <span class="word belize">laiku mokamą atlyginimą.</span>
    <span class="word pomegranate">socialines garantijas.</span>
    <span class="word green">galimybes tobulėti.</span>
    <span class="word midnight">nuolaidas tinklo parduotuvėse.</span>
  </p2>
    </center></div>
```

Comment: What is the text you want to center?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but I just wanted to point out that there's no such thing as a `p2` tag (only `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc.). You might wanna change that to `p`.

Comment: Ok, I need to arrange those black and colored strings in single line. And then center that line in screen. Exactly, center black+colored text line.

Comment: I have another p for whole html. This p2 is for text animation only. I'm not sure, how to set different style tags..

Comment: If your goal is to identify an individual `p` tag, you can use an id or a class, e.g. `<p id="animation">` or `<p class="animation">`.

Comment: So you need the whole line (black text + colored text) to be centered horizontally on the page each time the words change, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: There's a glitch in Mozilla. Chrome shows text in single line, Mozilla breaks it in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width: 100%` on `.text2` should get the whole block in center somewhat.

Also use `<p>` instead of `<p2>` and set its width to `max character count for your text. eg: 40ch`. And remove `width: 600px;` from `.word`

Hope it helps.